# How to switch from YAML array to mapping?

Tags: c#, yamldotnet

I'm trying to serialize a list of custom objects in YAML with YAMLDOTNET and I've the following result :

```
fruits:
- berry:
    size: 5
- banana:
    size: 6
- coconut:
    size: 10
```

Could you tell me how could I have the following result ?

```
fruits:
 berry:
   size: 5
 banana:
   size: 6
 coconut:
   size: 10
```

My FruitList class :

```
public class FruitList
{
  private List<Dictionary<string,Fruit> _fruits;

  public List<Dictionary<string, Fruits>> fruits { get => _fruits; set => _fruits = value; }

  public FruitList(List<Dictionary<string, Fruits>> f)
  {
    fruits =f;
  }
}
```

My Fruit class :

```
public class Fruit
{
   private int _size;

   public int size { get => _size; set => _size = value; }

   public Fruit(int s)
   {
    size = s;
   }
}
```

My main :

```
List<Dictionary<string, Fruit>> list = new List<Dictionary<string, Fruit>>();
Dictionary<string, Fruit> dic = new Dictionary<string, Fruit>();
Fruit f = new Fruit(3);

dic.Add("berry",f);
list.add(dic);
FruitList fl = new FruitList(list);

var serializerBuilder = new SerializerBuilder();
var serializer = serializerBuilder.Build();
var serializer = new Serializer();
var yaml = serializer.Serialize(fl);
Console.Write(yaml);
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a `List<Dictionary<string, Fruit>>`, you should have a single `Dictionary<string, Fruit>`.

Right now you have a list where each item is a dictionary containing a single elements, and your YAML output reflects that.